# SQL Server : parsing two values from one varchar with variable length

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a `varchar` column in a table. In this column, the structure is consistent, but the length can vary slightly.

Here are some examples of what I could be dealing with. Notice how the values conform to the same pattern but the numeric values contained within (policy number and the two account numbers) can vary slightly in length.

```
DECLARE @historyDescription1 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @historyDescription2 VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @historyDescription3 VARCHAR(50)

SET @historyDescription1 = 'Policy ZZ 998560-17 transferred from Account 0028397267 to Account 192135980'
SET @historyDescription2 = 'Policy ZZ 9985601-17-00 transferred from Account 128397267 to Account 792135980'
SET @historyDescription3 = 'Policy ZZ 998560789-17-00 transferred from Account 228397267 to Account 0192135980'
```

For each record, I need to select the first Account number and the second Account number. There will always be two present.

Something like...

```
SELECT [first parsed value]+','+[second parsed value]
FROM myTable
WHERE [...]
```

So that I get results like...

```
0028397267,192135980  
128397267,792135980  
228397267,0192135980
```

I've been playing around with `SUBSTRING`, `CHARINDEX`, `LEFT` and `RIGHT` to no avail. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### UPDATE A better approach

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(historyDescription VARCHAR(500));
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 ('Policy ZZ 998560-17 transferred from Account 0028397267 to Account 192135980')
,('Policy ZZ 9985601-17-00 transferred from Account 128397267 to Account 792135980')
,('Policy ZZ 998560789-17-00 transferred from Account 228397267 to Account 0192135980');


WITH SplitAtAccount AS
(
    SELECT historyDescription
          ,CAST('<x>' + REPLACE(
                          REPLACE(
                             REPLACE(historyDescription,' transferred from Account ','SplitThisHere'
                                    ),' to Account ','SplitThisHere'
                                  ),'SplitThisHere','</x><x>') + '</x>' AS XML) Casted 
    FROM  @tbl 
)
SELECT Casted.value('(x/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part1 
      ,Casted.value('(x/text())[2]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part2 
      ,Casted.value('(x/text())[3]','nvarchar(max)') AS Part3 
FROM SplitAtAccount
```

The result

```
Part1                     Part2       Part3
Policy ZZ 998560-17       0028397267  192135980
Policy ZZ 9985601-17-00   128397267   792135980
Policy ZZ 998560789-17-00 228397267   0192135980
```

Comment: This is pretty dank. I certainly was not on this track, but this works like a charm. I'll file this into my skill set. I'll figure out a way to merge the latter two columns.

Comment: @IanW. I'm glad, that you like it! About *I'll figure out a way to merge the latter two columns*: This is easy: Just use `+ ',' +` to concatenate Part2 and Part3. You might let the whole `SELECT` be a second CTE and query this as derived table.

Comment: @IanW. Btw: I had to look up *pretty dank*, thx for embiggening my vocabulary :-D

Answer (score 2):

I tried this, it seems to work with your sample values:

```
select substring(hist, pos1 + len1, pos2 - pos1 - len1 -1), substring(hist, pos2 + len2, lenhist - pos2 - len2 +1)
from (
select 
      pos1 = charindex('from Account', hist) 
    , pos2 = charindex('to Account', hist)
    , len1 = len('from Account')
    , len2 = len('to Account')
    , lenhist = len(hist)
    , *
from t
    ) x
```

I used a derived table to keep the expressions simple.

A [demo can be found here](http://rextester.com/PYUD30744).

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of things going on here that make this more challenging than it seems like it should be. The first is that you need to split your input string to separate the values. Then you need to stick them back together again. I am using the string splitter from Jeff Moden at sql server central.com. You can find his article, code and a great discussion on this topic here. http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/

Now that we can effectively split the string we just need to stick it back together. We can do that using STUFF and the FOR XML trick.

This works for the sample data you posted. The challenge will be if the values are not always in the location in the strings.

```
create table #Something (HistoryDescription varchar(200))

insert #Something
select 'Policy ZZ 998560-17 transferred from Account 0028397267 to Account 192135980' union all
select 'Policy ZZ 9985601-17-00 transferred from Account 128397267 to Account 792135980' union all
select 'Policy ZZ 998560789-17-00 transferred from Account 228397267 to Account 0192135980'

with parsedValues as
(
    select *
    from #Something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.HistoryDescription, ' ')
    where ItemNumber in (7, 10)
)

select HistoryDescription, 
    STUFF((select ',' + Item
        from parsedValues pv2
        where pv2.HistoryDescription = pv.HistoryDescription
        order by pv2.ItemNumber
        for xml path('')), 1, 1, '')
from parsedValues pv
group by pv.HistoryDescription
```

Answer (score 1):

charindex for know the start position of word 'Account'.
For second 'Account' word, you need a start index greater than first.

```
create table #test(
valor varchar(max)
)

insert into #test values('Policy ZZ 998560-17 transferred from Account 0028397267 to Account 192135980')
insert into #test values('Policy ZZ 9985601-17-00 transferred from Account 128397267 to Account 792135980')
insert into #test values('Policy ZZ 998560789-17-00 transferred from Account 228397267 to Account 0192135980')

select REPLACE(substring(
                                valor,
                                CHARINDEX('Account',valor)+8,
                                CHARINDEX('Account', valor,charindex('Account',valor))
                                )
                            ,' to Account ',
                            ',') as Accounts from #test
```

Comment: If the expected output is a comma separated string *in one piece* (as stated in the question), this is a very good answer (+1 from my side). All other answers try to split all values into separated columns, but OP did not ask for this actually :-D

Comment: Maybe so, but the point is, once it's separated out, you can do whatever you want, including gluing the parts back together as desired. Sometimes a better answer is giving someone extra tools they need to come up with more general solutions.

Comment: @pmbAustin, this is true, and this is the reason, why my own answer is offering the parts separated. OP can concatenate them easily... But this answer is beautifully minimalistic and this is a value in its own :-D

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the quick response.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a 'better' approach than the others, but it's simply an educational exercise in parsing strings, using CTEs to simplify some string expressions, and come out with the general results you desire. This is a more simple, if 'brute force' method, that doesn't rely on STUFF/FOR XML tricks. It further parses out the individual pieces, including policy number, in case you need those for other purposes.

```
CREATE TABLE #Something (HistoryDescription varchar(200))
INSERT #Something
SELECT 'Policy ZZ 998560-17 transferred from Account 0028397267 to Account 192135980' union all
SELECT 'Policy ZZ 9985601-17-00 transferred from Account 128397267 to Account 792135980' union all
SELECT 'Policy ZZ 998560789-17-00 transferred from Account 228397267 to Account 0192135980'

WITH HistoryDescriptionFragments AS (
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(HistoryDescription, 1, CHARINDEX(' transferred', HistoryDescription) - 1)) AS ReversedPolicyFragment,
       SUBSTRING(HistoryDescription, CHARINDEX('from Account ', HistoryDescription) + LEN('from Account ') + 1, LEN(HistoryDescription)) AS FromAccountFragment, 
       SUBSTRING(HistoryDescription, CHARINDEX('to Account ', HistoryDescription) + LEN('to Account ') + 1, LEN(HistoryDescription)) AS ToAccountFragment, 
       *
FROM #Something
), HistoryDescriptionParts AS (
SELECT REVERSE(SUBSTRING(ReversedPolicyFragment, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', ReversedPolicyFragment) - 1)) AS Policy, 
       SUBSTRING(FromAccountFragment, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', FromAccountFragment) - 1) AS FromAccount,
       ToAccountFragment AS ToAccount, 
       HistoryDescription AS OriginalText
FROM HistoryDescriptionFragments
)
SELECT Policy, FromAccount, ToAccount, FromAccount + ',' + ToAccount AS DesiredOutput
FROM HistoryDescriptionParts
```

This gives the results:

```
Policy           FromAccount  ToAccount   DesiredOutput
---------------  -----------  ----------  --------------------
998560-17        0028397267   192135980   0028397267,192135980
9985601-17-00    128397267    792135980   128397267,792135980
998560789-17-00  228397267    0192135980  228397267,0192135980
```

As an explanation... the first CTE is only necessary to simplify parsing out the policy number.  It splits the string into fragments that contain each piece you are interested in, REVERSING the policy fragment so its easier to pick off the number by just searing for the first space.  The second CTE refines the parsing to get just the data desired. The final SELECT simply selects from the CTE, and then joins the two pieces you are interested in, into the final "Desired Output".